# Combining Search clauses in Google Drive Java Client Api

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I would like to search for a file with a specific title in a specific folder.
As per https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters
I am trying following

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files.List request = service.files().list().set("q", "title=\'" + title+ "\'" + " and parents in [\'" + parentId + "\']");
```

Request parameter looks like the following

> {q=title='Tejal Kamble Resume.pdf' and parents in
>   ['0B0792kZaQwP6flBNdS01LUFidmtuNXIteEVnVDVPRTNDellxVENmWkkyejU3Y29Mc0JuRlE']}

Error Response

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid query",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid query"
}
```

FYI

Following code is working just fine

```
Files.List request = service.files().list().set("q", "title=\'" + title+ "\'" );
```

with following request parameter

> {q=title='Tejal Kamble Resume.pdf'}

Comment: lose the square brackets and no need to escape the single quote

Comment: r u sure? {q=title='Tejal Kamble Resume.pdf' and parents in 0B0792kZaQwP6flBNdS01LUFidmtuNXIteEVnVDVPRTNDellxVENmWkkyejU3Y29Mc0JuRlE} does not work

Comment: title = 'foo' and '0Bxxxx' in parents